# github action is running on feature branches and it should only run on main branch or release branch

Tags: github-actions

I have the following github action and it runs the action even if I create a feature branch with a name other than `main`, `master`, or `release`

What am I doing wrong?

```
#see https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zellwk/zellwk.com/master/.github/workflows/deploy.yml
name: deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - master
      - release
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1

      - name: Install SSH Key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        with:
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          known_hosts: unnecessary

      - name: Adding Known Hosts
        run: ssh-keyscan -p ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT}} -H ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

      - name: Set env file and jwk.json for release
        if: ${{ contains(github.ref_name, 'release') || github.ref == 'refs/heads/release' }}
        run: |
          echo "${{secrets.PRODUCTION_ENV }}" > .env.prod
          ln -sf .env.prod .env
          echo "${{secrets.PRODUCTION_JWK}}" | base64 --decode > jwk.json

      - name: Set env file and jwk.json for development
        if: ${{ !contains(github.ref_name, 'release') || github.ref != 'refs/heads/release' }}
        run: |
          echo "${{secrets.DEVELOPMENT_ENV }}" > .env.dev
          ln -sf .env.dev .env
          echo "${{secrets.DEVELOPMENT_JWK}}" | base64 --decode > jwk.json

      - name: Deploy with rsync for release
        if: ${{ contains(github.ref_name, 'release') || github.ref == 'refs/heads/release' }}
        # from ./bin/deploy.sh
        run: rsync -azvP -e "ssh -p ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}" --delete --exclude=node_modules --exclude=redis-data --exclude=.idea --exclude=.git --exclude=mongo_data --exclude=data01 --exclude=uploads --exclude=emails.txt --exclude=main --exclude=deno --exclude=app --exclude=database.sqlite --exclude=database.sqlite-journal --exclude=data ./ ${{secrets.SSH_USER}}@${{secrets.SSH_HOST}}:www/${{secrets.HOST_PATH_PROD}}/${{secrets.HOST_PROJECT}}
      #        run: rsync -avz -e "ssh -p ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}" ./dist/ ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}:/var/www/zellwk.com/

      - name: Deploy with rsync for development
        if: ${{ !contains(github.ref_name, 'release') && github.ref != 'refs/heads/release' }}
        # from ./bin/deploy.sh
        run: rsync -azvP -e "ssh -p ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}" --delete --exclude=node_modules --exclude=redis-data --exclude=.idea --exclude=.git --exclude=mongo_data --exclude=data01 --exclude=uploads --exclude=emails.txt --exclude=main --exclude=deno --exclude=app --exclude=database.sqlite --exclude=database.sqlite-journal --exclude=data ./ ${{secrets.SSH_USER}}@${{secrets.SSH_HOST}}:www/${{secrets.HOST_PATH_DEV}}/${{secrets.HOST_PROJECT}}

      - name: Post-Deploy script for release
        if: ${{ contains(github.ref_name, 'release') || github.ref == 'refs/heads/release' }}
        # from ./bin/deploy.sh
        run: ssh -t ${{secrets.SSH_USER}}@${{secrets.SSH_HOST}} -p ${{secrets.SSH_PORT}} \$HOME/www/${{secrets.HOST_PATH_PROD}}/${{secrets.HOST_PROJECT}}/bin/post-deploy.sh


      - name: Post-Deploy script for development
        if: ${{ !contains(github.ref_name, 'release') && github.ref != 'refs/heads/release' }}
        # from ./bin/deploy.sh
        run: ssh -t ${{secrets.SSH_USER}}@${{secrets.SSH_HOST}} -p ${{secrets.SSH_PORT}} \$HOME/www/${{secrets.HOST_PATH_DEV}}/${{secrets.HOST_PROJECT}}/bin/post-deploy.sh
  

      # - name: Restart App Server
      #   uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      #   with:
      #     host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
      #     username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
      #     key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      #     port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
      #     debug: true
      #     # from ./bin/post-deploy.sh
      #     #            if [ ${{ contains(github.ref_name, 'release') || github.ref == 'refs/heads/release' }} ]; then
      #     #           else
      #     #             cd $HOME/www/${{secrets.HOST_PATH_DEV}}/${{secrets.HOST_PROJECT}}
      #     #             deno upgrade
      #     #             sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
      #     #             sudo systemctl daemon-reload
      #     #             sudo systemctl restart ${{secrets.META_SERVICE_DEV}}
      #     #           fi
      #     script: |
      #       cd $HOME/www/${{secrets.HOST_PATH_DEV}}/${{secrets.HOST_PROJECT}}
      #       deno upgrade
      #       sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
      #       sudo systemctl daemon-reload
      #       sudo systemctl restart ${{secrets.META_SERVICE_DEV}}
```

it shouldn't run the action on push to a different branch ie: `feature1`

Comment: Here while you create a branch your workflow files also commit to that new branch. You can just remove the workflow file from the new branches.

Comment: You can also add an `environment: xxxxxx` to your deploy job and set its branch filters to these 3 branches.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things going on. Even though you've updated the YAML file in the main/master branch, it's likely that existing branches have a copy of the YAML file without the filter. You can fix that by cherry-picking the new YAML file into the existing branches.

The other thing you can do is define an Environment and add an `environment: xxxxx` to the YAML file and a branch filter on the environment. That will prevent people from running the deploy job against the environment.

In your repository settings, navigate to **environments** add an environment (any name will do) and then set the **Deployment branches** to **Selected branches** and then add the list of branches you want to allow to the list using the **➕ Add Deployment Branch**.

By putting all the production secrets in the list of **Environment Secrets** instead of the **Repository Secrets** you also prevent others from accessing these from any workflow that doesn't specifically target this environment.

[image: Add deployment branches]

Comment: how would I branch filter on environment?

Comment: Added a picture ☝️